# Android Studio Scanner Cannot FInd File Path

Tags: android, arraylist, java.util.scanner

Part of my application involves fetching a random word from a list of words I have in a text file, "wordlist.txt". I'm trying to use Scanner to get my activity to interact with it and put the words into a java ArrayList, but Scanner does not detect the file I'm directing it to, giving me an `Unhandled Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException`. What am I doing wrong? The relevant part of my code is below:

```
    File wordList = new File("app\\src\\main\\res\\wordlist.txt"); // generate reference to file

    final ArrayList<String> Dictionary = new ArrayList(); //create arraylist


    final Scanner checker = new Scanner(wordList);

    while (checker.hasNextLine()) {
        final String data = checker.nextLine();
        Dictionary.add(data);
    }
    checker.close();
```

Comment: Well I can't test this right now. But two things come to mind. Since you're running this on the emulator/android device you should use `/` instead of \\. An a absolute path must also always start with `/`.Try this: `File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);`

Comment: `if (!wordList.exists()){ Toast(.....); return;}` You use a non existent path in an Android device.

Comment: @FWeidinger That worked, but now it gives me an error saying that the file must end in .xml. Renaming it so this is true also gave me another error. Is there something else wrong with my code?

Comment: @shroomz that may be because you should NEVER place files directly into the `res` directory. Create a directory `raw` in `res` and you should be fine.